# How to remove an element from a JsArray in Google Web Tools?

Tags: json, gwt

I'm using **Google Web Tools**, and have a `JsArray`, which I'm populating with data from JSON.  I'm able to modify items within the array and add items to it, but I can't figure out how to *remove* an item from it.  I'm looking for something similar to the `pop()` method in JavaScript.

I can add an item to the array by using the `set(index,value)` method with an `index` that's out of the array's range, so I tried using `set(index,null)` to remove it, but the array still has the item, it's just null. (i.e. the array's length is unchanged.)

I'm currently using a hacky method whereby I create a new array, and copy all of the elements except the last one from the old to the new, but I'm hoping I don't have to live with that, because it's ugly.

```
private final JsArray<JsArrayInteger> popItemFromArray(
        JsArray<JsArrayInteger> oldArray) {
    // the createEmpty...  method is a native method which returns eval("[]")
    JsArray<JsArrayInteger> newArray = createEmptyIntIntArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < oldArray.length() - 1; i++) {
        newArray.set(i, oldArray.get(i));
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `pop()`, but there's... `shift()` :)

Either that or extend the `JsArray` class, something like this (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
public class JsArrayPop<T extends JavaScriptObject> extends JsArray<T> {

  protected JsArrayPop() {
  }

  public final native T pop() /*-{
    return this.pop();
  }-*/;

}
```

Comment: I don't see a `shift()` method--unless that was a joke that went over my head--but extending the `JsArray` class does the trick.

Comment: Maybe that's because I'm using my own 2.0-SNAPSHOT build, but I'm sure  that my version of `com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray<T>` has a `shift()` method (of course, it's just as simple as the `pop()` method, so you can add it easily).